# Administrator-Privilegs for a Single Method

Tags: c#, security

Im Currently working on an ApplicationLauncher / Autoupdater.
So for installing/updating an app to "Program Files", i need to request Administrator rights.

Well, since the Updater only needs to write something if new Versions are found, i tried to only
request the privilegs, if a new Version is found.

The updater is executed everytime, before the application launches, so asking "everytime" for Adminrights is no solution...

I searched a lot, and found the following:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = @"Administrators")]
    private void InstallOrUpdate(AppItem appItem)
```

but wenn i try to this, the updater throws a SecurityException...

> Request for principal permission failed.

What am i doing wrong?

Best regards,
dognose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot elevate permissions for the application once it's running.  In order to request the Administrators role, it will need to be done at startup time of the executable.

Your best option would be to have your updater either fire a different executable to do the `InstallOrUpdate`, or to re-run itself (with a different command line argument, potentially) with a request for elevated permissions at that point.

Comment: When I am doing administrative things in Windows, I see buttons in forms with the administrative icon next to them. When I click the button, UAC asks for elevated privileges. Are you saying that for every administrative button Windows is launching a new process? Or is something different happening there?

Comment: @Phil: Yes.  Basically, if you see a UAC prompt, you know a new process is going to be started at that point.

Comment: @Phil, a good example is the Windows Task Manager and the 'Show processes from all users' button. Clicking this doesn't just update Task Manager, it relaunches it with elevated permissions.

Comment: @Reed Copsey: Interesting. I could see that programming model getting hairy if you're creating software to run with regular user permissions and occasionally ask for elevated permissions.

Comment: @Phil: In general, it's a bad idea to do that.  Typically, if you want admin permissions, it should be for a specific, isolated purpose.. It makes sense if you think about it though - otherwise, you could get admin permissions to read data that would be used in a non-admin context, which would be dangerous from a security policy standpoint...

Comment: If you need admin permissions for multiple operations in your program, it's usually best to just require it across your entire program.  (You can lower permissions within your executable for sections via AppDomain policies, but not raise them...)

Comment: Ooh, so you're saying we can run with administrator privileges by default, and then specify which code will run with lower permissions? Do you have a link to some resources where I can read up on that?

Comment: @Phil: It's actually a lot more difficult than you'd expect.  You can setup an AppDomain with a lower policy, and run the code isolated in there.  It's not trivial, though.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046.aspx  (This is for .NET 4... CAS was used for <.NET 4, but is now obsolete...)

Comment: As @Reed Copsey, going down this route can get very complicated. I'd recommend have your update checking code in user-accessible methods. If an update is required launch a dedicated process that you can elevate.

Comment: It looks like regardless we will have to use two separate executables if we want to switch between permissions. Bummer. Thanks for the info.

Comment: okay, i'm trying to relaunch the updater with different parameters. i'll report, if it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

UAC elevation is *per-process*, i.e. the process as a whole is elevated, not per single method. The best course of action, would be to create a specific action process that requires elevated privileges, and launch that process from your updater when it actually needs to do some work. [This might help](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/28/Windows-Vista-_2D00_-Demand-UAC-elevation-for-an-application-by-adding-a-manifest-using-mt.exe.aspx).